# Re-use dimen.xml for target < 3.2 and > 3.2

Tags: android, android-resources

I got an app with various `dimen.xml`. selector: values / values-w300dp / values-w400dp / values-w600dp

Works fine on >3.2. But for < 3.2 I need to add the corresponding small/normal/large/xlarge selector.

**Any idea How I could re-use the same dimens.xml file for both selector?**

ie: I do NOT want to duplicate the file. I'm looking for something like the `<include>` for layout resource.

source:

section Combinations and Versions:

http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html